# Sort an array in javascript based on another array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I have an array of Mongoose ID's as follows:

```
       var ids =[
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId('58c2871414cd3d209abf4fc1'), 
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId('58c2871414cd3d209abf4fc0'),  
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId('58c2871414cd3d209abf5fc0')
      ];
```

When I call my Mongoose function to get the subdocuments that match these ids, the objects are returned to me in order of how they are found in the database. Can I reorder these based on the order of the above 'ids' array?

The data returned to me is as follows:

```
 [ { _id: 58c2871414cd3d209abf5fc9,
        companyname: 'Dell',
        position: 
         { _id: 58c2871414cd3d209abf5fc0,
           title: 'Software Engineer',
           location: 'Waterford',
           start: 'May 2017',
           term: 6,
           description: ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis erat vitae dsit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis erat vitae dolor tempus euismod non in mi' },
      { _id: 58ca9fd6588205e9c8f01431,
        companyname: 'Google',
        position: 
         { _id: 58c2871414cd3d209abf4fc0,
           title: 'Software Engineer',
           location: 'Waterford',
           start: 'May 2017',
           term: 6,
           description: ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis erat vitae dsit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis erat vitae dolor tempus euismod non in mi' },

      { _id: 58ca9fd6588205e9c8f01431,
        companyname: 'Google',
        position: 
         { _id: 58c2871414cd3d209abf4fc1,
           title: 'Software Engineer',
           location: 'Waterford',
           start: 'June 2017',
           term: 12,
           description: ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis erat vitae dsit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis erat vitae dolor tempus euismod non in mi' },
 ]
```

Is there any way of re-ordering these based on the original array? Note there are two _ids returned in the array, its the id for the position sub-document that I need to order. Really stuck if anyone could help that would be great!

**EDIT:**

My Node.js function is as follows:

```
    var ids =[mongoose.Types.ObjectId('58c2871414cd3d209abf4fc0'), mongoose.Types.ObjectId('58c2871414cd3d209abf4fc1'), mongoose.Types.ObjectId('58c2871414cd3d209abf5fc0')];
    User.aggregate( { $unwind : "$position" },
    { $match: { "position._id": {
      $in: ids }
    }
    }
    , function(err, results){

   //   results.sort((a, b) => {
           console.log(a+" "+b);
   //     return ids.indexOf(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(a.position._id)) 
 //       - ids.indexOf(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(b.position._id))
 //   })
         res.send({results:results});
    });

    });
```

Logged in console:

```
[object Object] [object Object]
[object Object] [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a compare function, the compare function finds the index of each element in `ids` using [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and giving it `element.postion.id`.

Here is the code:

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
    return ids.indexOf(a.position._id) - ids.indexOf(b.position._id)
})
```

I used `_id` as a string, You have to change it to `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`

I think it's done like that

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
    return ids.indexOf(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(a.position._id)) - ids.indexOf(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(b.position._id))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm a bit stuck on how to incorporate that into my code though, Ive updated my question to show my Node.js post request for getting the data.. would you have an idea if I'm doing it wrong? right now if I leave it where it is commented, the array is returned the same.. Thanks again!

Comment: You mean the code when the sort function is NOT commented returns the same array?

Comment: yeah, which is strange.. I'm unsure if I have it in the wrong place or something? @Khaled Hamed

Comment: Try adding `console.log(results)` before sending, also `console.log(a+" "+b)` inside the sorting function to know where the error is. Always test by `console.log()`-ing everything everywhere.

Comment: adding console.log(results) returns the information as expected (the order its returned from the database) but when I try to log anything referencing a or b nothing comes up .. I currently have console.log(a+" "+b) underneath the return statement and its blank. Also tried logging a on its own and also blank? which is weird

Comment: Try above the return not underneath it, return goes out of the function.

Comment: I have updated the question to show what the console logs when logging (a+" "+b) .. I'm unsure why its returning like that though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141982/discussion-between-khaled-hamed-and-user).